# How can I parse the title of a recipe on a website and write it to a text file?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Main Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import sys
import time
import re
import bs4 as bs



for num in range(680):
    address = ('http://www.diabetes.org/mfa-recipes/recipes/recipes-archive.html?page=' + str(num))
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(address).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup((html), "html.parser")

    for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("/recipes/20")}):
        find = re.compile('/recipes/20(.*?)"')
        searchRecipe = re.search(find, str(link))
        recipe = searchRecipe.group(1)
        urllinks = ('http://www.diabetes.org/mfa-recipes/recipes/20' + str(recipe))
        urllinks = urllinks.replace(" ","")
        outfile = open('C:/Users/cody/Desktop/python files/Projects/Scraper/Diabetes/recipe.txt', 'a')
        outfile.write(str(urllinks) + '\n')
        time.sleep(.1)


        f = open('recipe.txt', 'r')
        for line in f.readlines():
            wholeline = line.strip()
            sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(wholeline).read()
            soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'html.parser')
            body = soup.body
            for div in soup.find_all(True, {'class':['recipe_col_2','ingredients','instructions']}):
                outfile = open('C:/Users/cody/Desktop/python files/Projects/Scraper/Diabetes/recipe info.txt', 'a')
                outfile.write(div.text)
```

Title code:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.diabetes.org/mfa-recipes/recipes/2017-02-dijon-chicken-and-broccoli-and-noodles.html')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

body = soup.body
for title in body.find_all('h1'):
    print(title.text)
```

How can I take the title.text from the `title code` and integrate it into my `main code` so that it writes to the same text file. I'm also having trouble with another thing. Inside the text file it puts each recipe down twice and I don't want any duplicates, how can I fix this?

sample recipe website:
`http://www.diabetes.org/mfa-recipes/recipes/2017-02-dijon-chicken-and-broccoli-and-noodles.html`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add the h1 title the beginning of each recipe item in recipe_info.txt then this works:

```
for div in soup.find_all(True, {'class':['recipe_col_2','ingredients','instructions']}):
    #select and get text from h1
    title = soup.select_one('h1').getText()
    outfile = open('recipe_info.txt', 'a')
    #write it first
    outfile.write(title)
    outfile.write(div.text)
```

This worked when I ran it but I was encountering another error after the first recipe--"UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 206: ordinal not in range(128)"

If you're also encountering this problem then you may need to encode to 'utf-8' and then decode to read the file, which I won't get into.

Comment: That worked, thanks! Do you know why in my text file that there are two of each recipe and how to fix it?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't figure out the duplication issue. As a bandaid you could add an 'if div in _ ' conditional statement checking whether a given block of text has already been added to the text file before writing to it. Something along these lines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638659/how-to-prevent-duplicate-text-in-the-output-file-while-using-for-loop